# Save array value in a file

Tags: node.js

I have an array in node.js:

```
QL = [[],[],[],[]];
```

Time-after-time I want to save the information in a file. I run the node program, if file exists I want to load the array from it.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this simple way to store all array elements

```
var fs = require('fs');
var arr = [ [ 'text1' ],[ 'text2', 'text34','text444'],[ 'text3243', 'abc' ]]

var file = fs.createWriteStream('newFile.txt');
file.on('error', function(err) { /* Use error handler */ });
arr.forEach(function(item) { file.write(item.join(',') + '\n'); });
file.end();
```

Here all the array items appending in every new line of file

Answer (score 0):

Kind of depends how you want to save it in a file. You can call the File System module, native from nodeJS, that do a lot of things with file.

Before it, to check if the file exists, you can use fs.stat passing the name of the file, checking for the callback.

So, lets say you want just save the array as it are. You can pass it by argument like this:

```
const fs = require("fs");

let array = [[1,2,3],[34,9,10,50],[1,2,3]];

fs.writeFile('save1.txt',array,(data)=>{
console.log('done');
});
```

But if want to do some processing for each major array position, maybe you need to iterate over this array and call the same function each time.

More information can be found on NodeJS File System documentation
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to handle it.  You can try `outputJson` from `fs-extra` or the module `json-update`.

Here is an example saving:

```
require('json-update').update('data.json',{array:[[10,20],[1,2]]}).then(function(dat) {
  console.log(dat.test)
});
```

Here is an example loading: (file must exist)

```
require('json-update').load('data.json', function(err, arr) {
  console.log(arr.array);
});
```

Note with `json-update` it must be an object with properties, not just a plain array.  outputJson from `fs-extra` doesn't need that (but `json-update` has a locking mechanism to prevent multiple processes accessing at the same time).